# Dependent dropdown is not posting value

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

In update :

In this below code in update part there is 2 input box and 2 dropdown.When i select dropdown of course code corresponding subject code should display and when i update it should be updated to db.In my case when i select course code the subjectcode which exists changed to null(no value is prent).So anyone help me.

Controller:student_site

```
<?php

class Student_site extends ci_controller
{
    function index()
    {   
        $data = array();
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_view', $data);
    }

    function studentupdate()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }
                if($query = $this->student_model->get_course_code_records($exam_name))
        {
            $data['course_records'] = $query;
        }
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_all_coursesubject_records())
        {
            $data['all_coursesubject_records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
    }

    function studentcreate()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $data['exam_name'] = $exam_name;
        /*if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }*/
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_course_code_records($exam_name))  //get unique records of coursecode from the coursesubject table
        {
            $data['course_records'] = $query;
        }

        /*if($query = $this->student_model->get_subject_code_records($exam_name)) //write seperate function to get the the subject codes frm the coursesubject table based on the selected course code.
        {
            $data['subject_records'] = $query;
        }   */
        $this->load->view('student_update', $data);
    }   


    function subject_records()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_subject_records($exam_name,$course_name))
        {
            $data['subject_records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('subject_view', $data);
    }


    function create_student()
    {
    /*$data = $this->input->post();
    print_r($data);
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    $data=$this->input->post();*/
    $j=1; 
    $createstudent = $this->input->post('createstudent');

            if( $this->input->post('createstudent') != false ){
            foreach($createstudent as $row_id)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("register_number_" . $row_id, "Register No", "required|min_length[2]");
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules("name_". $row_id,"`Name`","required|xss_clean|min_length[1]");

                }
            }

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

                $data["message"]="";

                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
                $this->load->view("student_detail_view",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");

            }

    while($j<=$this->uri->segment(3))

   {

        $data = array(
        'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name'),
        'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number_'.$j),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name_'.$j),
        'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_name_id'.$j),
        'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_name'),

        );
        // $exam_name   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["exam_name_id".$j]);//
          $register_number=$this->input->post('register_number_'.$j);
            if ($register_number != "")
                {       
                $this->student_model->add_record($data);
                }
        //$course_code = $this->input->post('course_code_id'.$j);
        //$this->student_model->add_record($exam_name,$course_code,$subject_code,$data);
        //$this->student_model->add_record($data);
        $j++;
    }
    redirect('student_site', 'refresh');


    }

    function delete()
    {
    $this->student_model->delete_row();
     redirect('student_site', 'refresh');
    }
    function manage_student()
    {
        $data['title']="Manage Student";
            //query model to get data results for form
            $data=array();
            if($query=$this->student_model->get_student_records()){
            $data['records']=$query;
            }
            $editstudent = $this->input->post('editstudent');
            if( $this->input->post('editstudent') != false ){
            foreach($editstudent as $row_id)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("register_number_" . $row_id, "register_number", "required|min_length[2]");
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules("name_". $row_id,"`Name`","required|xss_clean|min_length[1]");
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules("course_code_". $row_id,"`CourseCode`","required|xss_clean|min_length[1]");
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules("subject_code_". $row_id,"`SubjectCode`","required|xss_clean|min_length[1]");

            }
            }
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data["message"]="";

                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
                $this->load->view("student_detail_view",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");

            } else {
                // single update - working
                if( $this->input->post('editstudent') != false )
                {
                    foreach ($editstudent as $row_id)
                    {
                        $data = array( 
                        'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number_'.$row_id),
                        'name' => $this->input->post('name_'.$row_id),
                        'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code_id'.$row_id),
                        'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_code_id'.$row_id),

                        );

                        $this->student_model->update_student_records( $row_id, $data );

                    }
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('dbaction', 'Selected Records have been updated successfully');
                    redirect('student_site', 'refresh');

                    }

            }
    }
    function update()
    {

        $data = array(
        'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name_id'),
        'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_code'),
        'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code'),
        );
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $register_number = $this->input->post('register_number');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $course_code = $this->input->post('course_code');
        $subject_code = $this->input->post('subject_code');
        $this->student_model->update_student_record($exam_name,$register_number,$name,$course_code,$subject_code,$data);
        $data = array();
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
    }
    function crud()
    {       
    }
    function deleting()
    {       
    }
    //No Need
    /*function studentdata()
    {
    $this->load->model("student_model");
    $data["result"]=$this->student_model->getdata("exam_name");
    $this->load->view("student_view",$data);
    }*/
    /*function delete()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        if($query = $this->student_model->delete_row($exam_name))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
    }*/
}

?>
```

view:student_detail_view

```
<section id="tables">
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = jQuery('#studenttable').dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

  });
   }); 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function get_studentdetails() {

    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentupdate',          
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#details').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentcreate',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#crud').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
}     

function CheckBoxVerification(From)
{
alert('hai');
    alert('hai:' $("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
    if(From == "Insert")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowInsert input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Create ...!');
        }
    }

    if(From == "Update")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowUpdate input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Update ...!');
        }
    }
}
  function get_subjectdetails1() {
    //var index = jQuery('#index').val();

    var course_name = jQuery('#course_name_id').val();
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    var exam_name = jQuery('#course_name_id>option:selected').text();
    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    var ssubject_code = jQuery('#ssubject_code_id').val();
    //var partsArray = exam_name.split('.');
    //alert("ssubject_code"+ssubject_code);
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'exam_name='+exam_name+'&course_name=' + course_name,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/subject_records',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            //alert ("data"+data);
            //for(var j = course_name; j < ssubject_code; j++)
        //{
            jQuery('#ssubject_code').empty().append(data);
        //}
        }

    });
} 

</script>

<?php 
    $attributes=array(
        'name'=>'updatecustomer',
        'id'=>'updatecustomer'
        );
    echo form_open('student_site/manage_student',$attributes);
?>
<div id="validation_failed">
    <?php
        echo validation_errors();
    ?>
    <?php $data = array();
        foreach ($course_records as $row)
        {
            $data[$row->course_code] = $row->course_code; 
        } 

        $subject_data = array();
        foreach ($all_coursesubject_records as $row)
        {
            $subject_data[$row->subject_code] = $row->subject_code; 
        }  


     ?>
     <div id="Processy">
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id='studenttable'>
<thead>
<tr font style='font-size:13px'>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Register Number</th>
<th>Name </th>
<th>Course Code</th>
<th>Subject Code</th>
</tr></thead>
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
<tr >
<td>
<?php echo anchor('student_site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete',array('onClick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete..?')")); ?>
</td>
<td id="rowUpdate">
<input type=checkbox name="editstudent[]" id="editstudent[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
</td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->register_number; ?>" ></td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" ></td>

<td >
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="course_code_id'.$row->id.'" onChange="get_subjectdetails112('.$row->id.')" '; 
        $js_name = 'course_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $data, $row->course_code, $js);
?>
</td>
<input type="hidden" name="index" id="index" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/>
<td>    
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="subject_code_id'.$row->id.'"'; 
        $js_name = 'subject_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $subject_data, $row->subject_code, $js);

?>

</td>
<?php 
   $row->id++;

?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
<center>
<br /><input type="submit" class="btn-success btn" value="Update Student"></center>

<?php else : ?>
<h2>No records were returned.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

view:student_update:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 function get_subjectdetails112(index) {
 alert ("enter first");
    //var index = jQuery('#index').val();
    //alert("index"+index);
    var course_name = jQuery('#course_code_id'+index).val();
    alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //var exam_name = jQuery('#course_name_id>option:selected').text();
    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    var ssubject_code = jQuery('#subject_code_id'+index).val();
    alert(ssubject_code);
    //var partsArray = exam_name.split('.');
    //alert("ssubject_code"+ssubject_code);
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'exam_name='+exam_name+'&course_name=' + course_name,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/subject_records',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            //alert ("data"+data);
            //for(var j = course_name; j < ssubject_code; j++)
        //{
            jQuery('#subject_code_id'+index).empty().append(data);
        //}
        }

    });
} 

</script>
```

Comment: can you simplify your code sample to just the relevant pieces?

Comment: ok i will edit my code @ koala_dev